# What is "Smart Standby"?

Tags: settings, 5.1-lollipop

My phone, a Blu Studio C 5+5 running Lollipop, has a toggle icon in the quick settings pulldown area labeled Smart Standby. I've found nothing in the phone's documentation or on Google that indicates what it does. Can somebody explain it?

*Note: I've discovered that when Smart Standby is enabled, [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) profiles which are tied to my calendar activate up to ten minutes late.*

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This doesn't seem a standard feature on Android. Can you find the respective feature on Android Settings? What menu is it under?

Comment: @AndrewT.: I'm sure it's a part of Blu's ROM; if it were AOSP, it presumably would be documented. There's no corresponding settings menu item that I've found.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found a German site https://durcheinandr.de/technik/smart-standby-welch-eine-option

To save you the hassle of translating, it states that enabling smart standby allows the device to automatically lock and turn the screen off when the phone is placed in your pocket, or on a flat surface.

*I barely remember my German. God, that was hard.*

Comment: In that case, it must not be working properly on my phone, because if I put it into my pocket, it's very likely to switch the screen on, and I'll find it on some unknown screen next time I look at it. In addition, with it enabled, Tasker tasks which are supposed to be triggered by calendar events run up to 10 minutes late.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Its all I could find. It's possible that it is just a buggy mess- might explain why it was hard to find documentation on it, since google could a phased it out.

Comment: Buggy mess is probably the size of it. I doubt this is a Google feature; I think it's more likely that the phone manufacturer added it.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Yeah, forgot that! :)